# Switch between GIF animations with QMovie and signals/slots in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I'm trying to use `QMovie` in Qt to play two GIFs.
When one gif ends, I need the next one to be played.

Herein lies the problem. I want to connect a signal to a slot in order to know when the GIF animation ends. Here is a sample of my code:

```
#include "abv.h"
#include "ui_abv.h"
#include "qmovie.h"
#include "qlabel.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

using namespace std;

abv::abv(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
    ui(new Ui::abv)
{
    QString project = projectGifs();//projectGifs() is a function stated in my header that sends over a randomly selected gif
    QMovie* movie = new QMovie(project);
    if (!movie->isValid())
    {
        cout << "The gif is not valid!!!";
    }
    QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
    QObject::connect(
                movie, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)),
                this, SLOT(abv::abv()));//stop animation and get new animation
    label->setMovie(movie);
    movie->start();
}

void abv::detectEndFrame(int frameNumber)
{
    if(frameNumber == (movie->frameCount()-1))
    {
        movie->stop();
    }
}

abv::~abv()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

At `if(frameNumber == movie->frameCount()-1)`, I receive an error stating that the movie is undeclared. It also states that `left of '->framecount' must point to class/struct/union/generic type`.

The same happens with `movie->stop();` : it appears that I can access the variable `movie`.

I also cannot seem to replace my movie with a new GIF, due to the same issue.
How do I fix this? What should I be looking for to insert a new animated GIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for removing the error, just declare your `QMovie` in your header file (which I believe is the one named `abv.h`).

In your .h :

```
private : 
    QMovie* _movie;
```

In your .cpp :

```
abv::abv(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
    ui(new Ui::abv)
{
    QString project = projectGifs();
    _movie = new QMovie(project); // this line changes
    ...
```

Now, you connect the signal `frameChanged(int)` to the constructor `abv::abv()`. It won't work because :

- mainly, your constructor can't be a slot ;
- the signature is not the same (the slot must take an `int` as a parameter, like the signal does)

Moreover, why are you doing it like this? The signal frameChanged(int) is emitted each time a new image is sent to the user(!). You are currently telling your program to launch a new GIF everytime a frame changes. Your code won't work this way.

If I understand well, you just have to connect the signal [QMovie::finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#finished) to a slot where you will call another GIF. Your `QLabel` will have to be a class variable as well. Something like this :

In your .h :

```
private
    QMovie* _movie;
    QLabel* _label;

public slots :
    void startNewAnimation();
```

And in your .cpp :

```
abv::abv(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
    ui(new Ui::abv)
{
    QString project = projectGifs(); //projectGifs() is a function stated in my header that sends over a randomly selected gif
    _movie = new QMovie(project);
    if (!_movie->isValid())
        cout << "The gif is not valid!!!";
    _label = new QLabel(this);
    QObject::connect(
                _movie, SIGNAL(finished()),
                this, SLOT(startNewAnimation())); //stop animation and get new animation
    _label->setMovie(_movie);
    _movie->start();
}

void abv::startNewAnimation()
{
    // here you need to call your new GIF
    // and then you just put it in your label

    // you can also disconnect the signal finished() if you want

    QString newGIF = projectGifs();
    _movie = new QMovie(newGIF);
    _label->setMovie(_movie);
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try in a few hours (when I get home). After having gone back and read the QMovie documentation and example, I realized you and those documents were completely correct with the private variables - I totally missed them.

In response to the frameChanged(int) vs. finished(), I tried both and it was in case my video was looping (gif images for example). I wanted to have a backup if it detected the genuine last frame. I'll change it to finished() though! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, give it a try and if you have more questions, don't hesitate to come back here :)

Comment: Alright, I am home now. I gave it a whirl and it's throwing a whole ton of errors (unexpected token 'class'. Did you forget a ';') and a whole ton of other specifier -int assumed errors as well. Most of this stuff is located in the moc_abv.cpp file and qinputmethod.h file. Not quite sure what to make of that.

Comment: Edit: I've fixed it and it appears to be on the path to working! I'll come back  and either PM you or post here to ask another question. But as far as I'm concerned, this has solved my issue! :) Thank you IAmlnPLS!

Comment: Glad to hear it :) hope you will make it work, sounds fun to code !

Comment: It sort of is! It's the first time I'm playing with QT and C++. I'm a python guy, mostly.